# show div based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.formbox').hide();
            $('#dropdown').change(function() {
              $('.formbox').hide();
              for(i=1;i<=$(this).val();i++){
                     $('#witness' + i).show();
              }
            });
          });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" value="{{course}}">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option> 
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <hr>
      <table>
        <tr>
        <td>

          <div id="witness1" class="formbox">stuff</div>
          <div id="witness2" class="formbox">stuff</div>
          <div id="witness3" class="formbox">stuff</div>
          <div id="witness4" class="formbox">stuff</div>
          <div id="witness5" class="formbox">stuff</div>
          <div id="witness6" class="formbox">stuff</div>
          <div id="witness7" class="formbox">stuff</div>
          <div id="witness8" class="formbox">stuff</div>

        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</body>
```

What I want is when you select option 1, you see the witness1 div. When you select option 2, you see both witness1 and witness2. When you select option 3, you see witness1, witness2 and witness 3...and so on.

Here is a live example:

http://pr0digy.me/witness.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: jquery file is not called.

Comment: It works if you include the jQuery library, http://jsfiddle.net/GwUUb/

Comment: Wow I feel dumb. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include jQuery. You need it to use $.